# Drupal 7 site take more time to add and update

Tags: performance, drupal, drupal-7, addition, edit

My drupal 7 site takes more.. time to node add (node/add) and update (node/edit). Please anyone help me to reduce the time of node add and edit

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd do this:

- Try disabling modules you installed recently. Or revert/switch off new functionality. I assume when you say *takes more.. time* you compare it to some time in the past when it was better. Try to recall what were the changes to the website configuration or modules set since then and roll them back one by one.
- On your local copy of the website enable Devel module and look at the amount of queries executed while adding or updating a node. look at the most slow ones. It may lead you to some more narrow question.
- The last resort I'd say - profiling code with xdebug but I'm not sure how deep you are with PHP development and debugging. This one requires skills in configuring your web-server, and using a PHP IDE or at least an xdebug profile reader (e.g. webgrind)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing fresh Drupal 7 on same server (i.e. create staging sub-domain) and see will on it adding/updating also take long time. If so, problem is with server obviously.

If it's fast with fresh Drupal then problem is on your site - try turning off modules one by on (again on staging domain preferably) until it starts working at normal speed. Must be that some module is causing the problem.